# how to use django redirect when we have dynamic url

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-4.0

i have dynamic uls

```
urlpatterns=[path('author/<str:pk>/',views.authorview,name='author')]`
```

and i want to use it in redirect

```
def authorview(request,pk):
    user=User.objects.get(id=pk)
    a=Blogmodel.objects.filter(author=pk)
    context={'user':user,'a':a}
    return render(request,'blogapp/authorview.html',context)
def loginview(request):`
    `if request.method=='POST':`
    `username = request.POST.get('username')`
    `password = request.POST.get('password')`
    `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`
    `if user is not None:`
      ` login(request, user)`
       `return redirect('profile')`                                      # i want to use it here

    else:
        return redirect('/blogapp/signup/')
    #context={'username':username,'password':password}

 return render(request,'blogapp/loginview.html')`
```

i am not able to use this (/str:pk/)  on redirect

Comment: have you tried this `return redirect('author',pk=user.pk)` ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow yeah I got error reverse for author not found

Comment: could you please share your view `authorview` ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow added author view

Comment: first change your url to this `urlpatterns=[path('author/<int:pk>/',views.authorview,name='author')]` and add this `return redirect('author',pk=user.pk)` after login(request,user).second there is a typo in your `authorview`  change this `Blogmodel.objects.filter(author=pk)` to `Blogmodel.objects.filter(author_id=pk)`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow still i got same error

Comment: Update your question and show the error(the full traceback) ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow  NoReverseMatch at /blogapp/login/
Reverse for 'author' not found. 'author' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: instead of this `return redirect('author',pk=user.pk)` try this `return redirect(f'author/{user.pk}/')`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow hey can you suggest me some good source from where i can learn django

Comment: I personnally advice three websites:1)https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html 2) the official documentation 3)https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django after make good projects

Comment: Did you declare a namespace for the author path?

Comment: @dacx yeah i used it like this app_name='blogapp'